# Select all the groups that meet condition at least once

Tags: python, pandas, filter, any

I want to keep all the rows of the groups that meet a condition at least once. In other words, I want to drop the groups that do not meet the condition at least once.

I've been looking around for a few hours and could not find a solution. [This was the closest I got](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38830423/groupby-and-any-all) but I could not implement the answer.

I have the following data frame:

```py
test = pd.DataFrame({"Gr":[1,1,2,2],"Bk":[9,1,8,5]})
print(test)

   Gr  Bk
0   1   9
1   1   1
2   2   8
3   2   5
```

I want to group by `test["Gr"]` and select all the groups where `test["Bk"] == 9` at least once to get to this:

```
# Drop Gr 2 because they didn't meet Bk == 1 in any of its rows.
   Gr  Bk
0   1   9
1   1   1
```

I would have thought this could be easily achieved by combining `groupby()` and `.any()` without the need of lambda functions.

I tried this:

```py
test.groupby("Gr").filter(lambda x: (x.Bk == 9).all())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a possiblity without groupby. Just check all entries for equality to 9, get the group of this entries and slice the whole dataframe for the extracted groups.

```
test[test.Gr.isin(test[test['Bk'].eq(9)].Gr)]
```

result

```
    Gr  Bk
0   1   9
1   1   1
```

Answer (score 3):

Easy to understand `filter`

```
test.groupby('Gr').filter(lambda x : x['Bk'].eq(9).any())
   Gr  Bk
0   1   9
1   1   1
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `GroupBy.transform` with `eq.any` to check within each group if `any` of the values are equal (`eq`) to `9`:

```
mask = test.groupby('Gr')['Bk'].transform(lambda x: x.eq(9).any())
test[mask]
```

**Output**

```
   Gr  Bk
0   1   9
1   1   1
```

Comment: This works perfectly, but why is the lambda part necessary?

Comment: Since we use `transform` to get an equal length array back of `True` and `False` which indicates if the row should be returned in our result. Lambda is necessary since we apply multiple pandas methods (`eq` and `any`).

Comment: Thanks man. One last question: are lambda functions executed row by row?

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
test =test[test['Gr'].apply(lambda x: x in [key for key in test['Gr'][test['Bk'].eq(9)]])]
test
```

Output:

```
    Gr  Bk
0   1   9
1   1   1
```

Answer (score 1):

pretty straightforward approach here..

checks where test['Bk'] is equal to 9, and gets the corresponding values in test['Gr'], then reduces the df down to only the rows where these values of test['Gr'] are occurring

```
test[test['Gr'].isin(test[test['Bk']==9]['Gr'])]
```

result :

```
   Gr  Bk
0   1   9
1   1   1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume there is only single `Bk=9` to each group of `Gr` . This is a crazy and overkilled way using `merge`  :D

```
test.merge(test.loc[test.Bk.eq(9),'Gr'], on='Gr')

Out[227]:
   Gr  Bk
0  1   9
1  1   1
```

---

Note: it still works on multiple `9` per group. It just needs `drop_duplicates`, but I think at that point it gets too complicated and not fun anymore