# Problem with Sorting and Selecting Python Pandas Problem

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having problem in sorting and grouping/selecting data from a table using Pandas DataFrame. Attached is the image for better understanding of my problem. I would like to get DataFrame 2 from DataFrame1.

I would appreciate your kind help (by providing code/python) in this regard.

Problem detail: I want to select the Snowplow crash from a big dataset where with the same crash ID another or more vehicle is involved.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPfog.png)

Comment: `df.groupby('ID').filter(lambda x: x['Type'].eq('Snowplow').any())` like [BENY's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57549407/15497888)

Comment: `df[df['Type'].eq('Snowplow').groupby(df['ID']).transform('any')]` or `df[df.groupby('ID')['Type'].transform(lambda x: x.eq('Snowplow').any())]` as in [Erfan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57549160/15497888)

Comment: I assume the entry `10045,Nissan,2003,Car` was also to be included in DF2.

Comment: Thanks, the code worked perfectly. Yes, Nissan row is to be included as well, by mistake I didn't include it in dataFrame2